# ECONNRESET with postgres and sequelize on nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Well we are using `nodejs v10.13.0` along with it`sequelize 4.42.0` to make communication with our `postgres 9.2` bank, our server is in AZURE it has 8GB of HAM, 2 CPU and it is CentOS 7. In the bank we are using the 2 `schemas` approach, and in fact will come more, we think that could possibly be a problem, but we are not sure of that. So we are having several connection problems, in some moments and in some `querys` the`sequelize` to report an error in the log.

> (node:22240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: read ECONNRESET
>   warning.js:18
>       at Query.formatError (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:363:16)
>       at query.catch.err (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:86:18)
>       at tryCatcher (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:690:18)
>       at _drainQueueStep (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
>       at _drainQueue (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
>       at Async._drainQueues (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
>       at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
>   (node:22240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 10)

We have already tried to make some updates to the configuration file according to the site [PGTune](https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/)

```
# DB Version: 9.2
# OS Type: linux
# DB Type: web
# Total Memory (RAM): 8 GB
# CPUs num: 2
# Data Storage: ssd

max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 2GB
effective_cache_size = 6GB
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 10485kB
checkpoint_segments = 32
```

When we made these settings the first interesting problem happened, he complained about `kernel shmmax` studying we found that`PGTune` itself informs us that we need to change then we apply the changes in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file by adding the lines

```
kernel.shmmax=4294967296
kernel.shmall=1048576
```

Also we tried to increase the capacity of the server from 4GB to 8GB but we also had no success. Anyway we are not understanding what the problem is, the error message is unclear (at least for me).

Comment: Look for messages in the PostgreSQL log file.

Comment: Nothing appears

Comment: Actually this is the message that appears in the log, LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection timed out

Comment: That sounds like a network problem. Is there a firewall that drops connection packets?

Comment: Yeah, how can I see if it would be him?

Comment: Ask your network administrator...

Comment: I asked him here, we will analyze this and I will return an opinion, although it is possible that is happening this same, in time before he asked of an ip that the firewall was blocking, it can certainly be about this issue.